# EF Core 2.1 Update related data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1

my edit controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Put(long id, [FromBody] Student student)
 {
        var p = await _Context.Students
            .Include(t => t.PhoneNumbers)
            .Include(t => t.StudentCourses)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);

        if (p == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        p.PhoneNumbers = student.PhoneNumbers;
        p.StudentCourses = student.StudentCourses;
        _Context.Update(p);
        await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

When i try to update the related entities im getting the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'PhoneNumber' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

Am i doing the updation in a  wrong way. Please help me to correct it. Also i'm not sure about difference between Direct _context.update() and _context.students.update(). Please enlighten me.

Comment: Try to remove the _context.Update(p) line. EF should track changes itself and in that case SaveChanges should do the work.

Comment: Thanks @Jaume Also i'm not sure about difference between Direct _context.update() and _context.students.update(). Please explain me.

Comment: Well, both have similar or exact the same effect. Both modify state of an entity to Modified. You have to be aware that despite you changed only one property in entity, using Update will mark ALL properties as modified, so query passed to db will contain all properties. Look what the documentation states: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-2.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-2.1 (there are no differences between DbSet.Update and Context.Update)

Comment: @Jaume Still i face the issue after removing _context.Update(p) line. System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'PhoneNumber' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.